# Dash ("–") breaks aspose.pdf xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, aspose, aspose.pdf

I have an xsl-fo xslt file, and it generates blank pages, along with the standard "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem" error message.

I found that the issue was due to the text I was writing into the pdf contained dashes "–" and when I removed characters, the pdf was rendered successfully.

does anyone know why this "–" character would cause the xsl-fo pdf process should fail? everything I have read says this is not a special character and I shouldn't worry about encoding it.

*Update* here is a link to the Aspose forum's post I created:
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/593149/593149/showthread.aspx#593149

*Update #2* I found the issue was not the forward slash, but an encoding issue with dashes (I have updated the questions content, sorry for the confusion) at this point i am still looking for an answer, but I confused the differences between my working xml data, and my not working xml.

Comment: Is the slash only bad in the VariableName or also in the VariableLabel?

Comment: We need to see what the template named `variableLabel` does.

Comment: no, I have other examples from customers where the slash is in other text components. this was the clearest, simplest steps to recreate I could find. @MartinHonnen I am not sure what you mean by "see what the template named variableLabel does" we are taking the xml value above, and injecting it into an fo:table cell. that's it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have added the whole for-each block. let me know if that was the information you were wanting.

Comment: Are you producing a simple PDF or are you producing a fillable PDF Form and using the label as the name of the field?

Comment: I am creating a readonly pdf of the data found in the xml. no input fields are added to the form. Thanks for the question @KevinBrown

Comment: You have `<xsl:call-template name="variableLabel">` in there which passes on the elements so I would like to see what that template does.

Comment: Well, while I would like to also see the template ... I can think of nothing in the world that would cause issues as you mention short of trying to create fields in the PDF in an Acroform. Having a "/" or any other character in a text string is nothing short of what seems to be a bug in the software you are using.

Comment: yeah, I am thinking the same thing. I linked this stack overflow to the company (Aspose) but it looks like their link functionality doesn't work

Comment: Sorry guys, I found the issue was not the forward slash, but some older data that did not have an encoded dash. when I removed the forward slash, the underlying data was saved in an encoded format that corrected the issue. *however* I am confused why the "–" character would blow up my pdf generation so spectacularly!

Comment: Your confusion is perfectly understood. it shouldn't. Your have done the right thing and reported as a bug.

Comment: Looks like this was reported fixed in October 2015.  We had a customer report a similar issue when converting a Word document to PDF when the title had a "long" dash in it.  I was not able to duplicate the problem, and am trying to see if it was fixed in a version pervious to Words 21.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug was found back in 2015, and the issue was resolved regarding the handling of this long dash (-) character. I recommend upgrading if you have not done so!